# Phpstorm installed in etc/opt/ instead of opt/

Tags: filesystem

So I am coming from Windows background and after a lot of reading about the filesystem here ( on Ubuntu ) I am still pretty confused. I've installed chrome and sublime-text which both went to `opt/` directory ( the add-ons directory as I understood ) but `PhpStorm` went to `etc/opt/` directory. The right place for `PhpStorm` should be the `opt/` directory I think. What amd I doing wrong ?

Comment: How did you install phpstorm, what commad did you use? The `/etc` folder is for system wide application settings!

Comment: Not pretty sure. It was about a month ago and I was forced to do some other stuff that time ... But it should be in the `otp/` right ? I think I used those lines:
`wget http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2017.1.4.tar.gz
tar -xvf PhpStorm-2017.1.4.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-171.4694.2/bin/
./phpstorm.sh`

Comment: And let me ask these files in `/etc` are there not phpstorm ettings files, how did you come to the conclusion that it was installed there? Please run `sudo ls -la /etc/opt` and lets see what in there!

Comment: `drwxr-xr-r    8   root   4096   сеп   11   21:44   phpstorm`. Only that folder. In the folder I got `bin/  build.txt  help/  Install-Linux-tar.txt  jre64/  lib/  license/  plugins/`

Comment: That is just wrong, `bin` aren't supposed to be in that location at all. It appears you passed a `PREFIX` option when installing. You may have to move it to `/opt` or reinstall

Comment: The right command should have been `sudo tar xfz PhpStorm-*.tar.gz -C /opt/`! Now run `sudo mv /etc/opt/phpstorm /opt/`, assuming there is a `phpstorm` folder there else the command won't work!

Comment: Thank you very much! Guess I did  set the wrong directory manually.